# I'm getting this.get() is undefined in ember

Tags: javascript, events, ember.js, undefined, global

I'm trying to create an event bus to be able to trigger some ui events throughout my app. I've followed the instructions here: http://emberigniter.com/communication-between-distant-components/

I load my event bus as a service into a component property called ui but for some reason I get this error: `TypeError: this.get(...) is undefined`, which is weird, since it should be, right? It doesn't matter if I run the code in init or later in didInsertElement, same error. What can I do?

```
// services/ui.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend(Ember.Evented);

//components/side-menu.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend(Ember.Evented, {
  ui: Ember.inject.service(),
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.get('ui').on('side-menu:toggle', this.actions, 'toggle');
  },
  actions: {
    toggle: function() {
      this.$().sidebar('toggle');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to mix `Ember.Evented` into your component. Not sure why that would cause the error you're seeing, but removing it is worth a try.

Comment: Try using `.on('init')` instead of overriding `init`.

Comment: @rollingBalls that is very poor advise, you should not use `on` for lifecycle hooks. You should override them and call super, just like OP did.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It was because I was binding `this.actions` and get wasn't defined on the actions property, I guess. When I instead made a method called toggle and bound `this` instead it worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Generally thats why I would recommend to always use `Ember.get(target, 'name')` instead of `target.get('name')`.

Comment: Maybe [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40606827/difference-between-ember-get-and-this-get/40607558#40607558)