# Difference between Ember.get() and this.get()

Tags: ember.js

I'm new to Ember and it keeps confusing me about the difference between `this.get()` and `Ember.get()`. Can someone explain them briefly?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Welcome to Ember ;-)

Every object that extends [Ember Observable](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.9.1/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/observable.js#L100) mixin supports the `get()` method (among others).

When you call `this.get()`, the `this` must refer to such an object (Route, Controller, Component, your own class that extends Ember.Object and so on). Calling `get()` on plain object would cause a failure. Let me show the difference:

```
const emberObjectInstance = Ember.Object.create({
 name: 'Bala'
});

emberObjectInstance.get('name'); // returns 'Bala'

const plainObject = { name: 'Bala'};
plainObject.get('name'); // causes a failure since get() is not a function
```

However, using `Ember.get()` successes in both cases:

```
Ember.get(emberObjectInstance, 'name'); // returns 'Bala'
Ember.get(plainObject, 'name');         // returns 'Bala', too
```

which can be also written with imports as follows

```
import { get } from '@ember/object';

get(emberObjectInstance, 'name'); // returns 'Bala'
get(plainObject, 'name');         // returns 'Bala', too
```

Note: not to forget, calling either of `get()` makes computed property get computed (in the most common cases, I don't want to dive deep now - lazy computation, volatile extensions etc), but for the sake of understanding the difference, we can work with plain values.

From own experience, I am using `Ember.get()` everywhere I know a plain object might be the object whose property I need to retrieve. A nice example is `setupController()` hook into which I may pass plain object from my unit tests to test `setupController()`'s functionality.

```
// some route:
setupController(controller, model){
    this._super(...arguments);

    const name = Ember.get(model, 'name'); // ***

    controller.set('isNamePresentOnSetup', Ember.isPresent(name));
}

// in my unit tests I can use plain object:
...
const modelMock = { name: 'Bala' }; // plain object is enough because I use Ember.get instead of model.get() (see ***)?
const controllerMock = Ember.Object.create(); // has to be Ember.Object since I use controller.set() within setupController()

subject.setupController(controllerMock, modelMock);
assert.ok(controllerMock.get('isNamePresentOnSetup'), "property 'isNamePresentOnSetup' set up correctly if model name is present");
...
```

I could also user `Ember.set(controller, 'isNamePresentOnSetup', Ember.isPresent(name))` and then pass plain controller mock into `setupController()`, too.

I think this is a good start since you are new in Ember and I am sure Ember gurus would have much more to add. 
Relevant Ember docs:

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.9.0/object-model/

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.9.0/object-model/computed-properties/

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.9.0/object-model/reopening-classes-and-instances/

**UPDATE:**
Using `get()` with [chained paths](https://emberjs.com/blog/2018/04/13/ember-3-1-released.html#toc_es5-getters-for-computed-properties-2-of-4) works different than working with POJOs.
For example in `objectInstance.get('a.b.c')` if `b` is `undefined` the return value is `undefined`. Converting this to `objectInstance.a.b.c` when b is `undefined` would instead raise an exception.

Comment: Thanks for explaining in brief.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the explanation.
In "const modelMock = {name: 'Bala'}; // plain object is enough because I use Ember.set instead of model.set(), you see?" , it is actually Ember.get() ryt??

Answer (score 4):

There is none. `foo.get('bar')` is equivalent to `Ember.get(foo, 'bar')`. However because `foo.get` is defined on `Ember.Object` you can only call `.get()` on Ember Objects. `Ember.get()` will work on all ember objects. On Ember Objects `Ember.get(foo, 'bar')` is equivalent to `foo.get('bar')`, on every other object its equivalent to `foo['bar']`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Please note that using `Ember.get()` or `this.get()` is not needed anymore for most use cases if running Ember >= 3.1, which was released in April 2018. You could now use native ES5 getters. A quick introduction to this change could be found in [release notes for Ember 3.1](https://www.emberjs.com/blog/2018/04/13/ember-3-1-released.html#toc_es5-getters-for-computed-properties-2-of-4). It's discussed more in detail in [RFC 281](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0281-es5-getters.md).

There is a codemode available that helps you transition to ES5 getters: [es5-getter-ember-codemod](https://github.com/rondale-sc/es5-getter-ember-codemod) It could be run as part of [ember-cli-update](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-update#readme).

Please not that using `Ember.get()` or `this.get()` is not deprecated. It's still needed for some edge cases, that are listed in release notes linked above:

> In fact there are several cases where you must still use get:
>
> - If you are calling get with a chained path. For example in this.get('a.b.c') if b is undefined the return value is undefined. Converting this to this.a.b.c when b is undefined would instead raise an exception.
> - If your object is using unknownProperty you must continue to use get. Using an ES5 getter on an object with unknownProperty will cause an assertion failure in development.
> - Ember Data returns promise proxy objects when you read an async relationship and from other API. Ember proxy objects, including promise proxies, still require that you call get to read values.

Please note that there is a special case if using [`ember-changeset`](https://github.com/poteto/ember-changeset). It provides it's own `.get()` implementation. Therefore `Ember.get(this, 'value')` and `this.get('value')` have different results if `this` is an `ember-changeset`. You find more information on that case in [documentation of ember-changeset](https://github.com/poteto/ember-changeset#get).