# What is the difference between set(this, 'agentName', 'John') and this.set('agentName', 'John') in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

The same is true for 'get' methods too. Like `get(this, 'agentName')` and `this.get('agentName')` returns the same value.

In the official [ember doc for get method](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_get), it shows that we are supposed to pass 2 values to get. Then how does `this.get('agentName')` work accurately?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Ember.get() and this.get()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40606827/difference-between-ember-get-and-this-get)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.get(...)` is a shortcut for `Ember.get(this,...)`. However it is only available on ember objects, so only `Ember.get` works in plain js objects.

Have a look at [`this.get(...)` implementation](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.12.0/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/observable.js#L209).

Answer (score 2):

The getter and setter in Ember has been upgraded to handle `unknown property`, `computed property` and `observers`. Not many people would use `setUnknownProperty()` hook or the `unknownProperty()` hook with get and set, but there are computed properties and observers throughout most people's code. More on [computed properties](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/object-model/computed-properties/) and [observers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/object-model/observers/).

So, the basic difference between your `set()` and `this.set()` has to do with the context of your function. When you call just set(), it has to be defined in that scope or imported from somewhere to get things done. Howeve, with this.set() the scope here is **this**. Depending on where you are calling the function the scope changes. For instance if you are in a **component**, `this` refers to the `component` class itself. Similar would be the case with controllers, routes and other ember objects. If you have object of your own and it does not extend any of ember classes, then `this` would still work with how it does in any other JavaScript code. So it will fall back to default [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) in JavaScript.

As you may have realized by now, when you call `get(this, 'foo')`, you are calling JavaScript's getter function and pass it the current context with property to be searched for. And when you say `this.get('foo')` you are calling `get()` from `Ember.Object` class, which can handle things I mentioned above. And as @Lux mentioned this.get('foo') is simplified to call Ember.get(this, 'foo').

Hope this helps. I do encourage reading [Ember guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/) and [API docs](https://emberjs.com/api/). Curent ember-cli and ember-data version is @2.12.0