# What is the difference between this.set and Ember.set

Tags: ember.js

Is there any difference between following two conditions this.set('firstName','ember') and Ember.set(this,'firstName','ember')

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43285202/what-is-the-difference-between-setthis-agentname-john-and-this-setagen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between set(this, 'agentName', 'John') and this.set('agentName', 'John') in Ember?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43285202/what-is-the-difference-between-setthis-agentname-john-and-this-setagen)

Answer (score 7):

Ember's computed property chain and observers rely on you calling *object*.set() on the object in question. You will often see warnings to this effect if you forget.

However, it's possible to get into a situation where you may not know if the object you've been handed is an Ember.Object or just a plain javascript object. That's where `Ember.set()` comes in handy - it works on both types of objects.

```
const setFoo(target, value) {
    Ember.set(target, 'foo', value);
}

const a = {foo:null};
const b = Ember.Object.create({foo:null});

// both calls are valid because we use Ember.set()
setFoo(a, 'johnny');
setFoo(b, 'bravo');
```

Here's the official documation that's kinda helpful: [Ember.set()](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.13/classes/Ember/methods/set?anchor=set)