# Logic for when 'this' is valid from component to service

Tags: ember.js

I'm flummoxed.  I have this working, but I have no idea why.  Here's the setup...
The service, stripped...

```
export default Ember.Service.extend({
    editableCat: null,
    saveCatChanges() {
        var editCat = editableCat;
this.get('editstate').saveJournalChanges();
...
```

The caller, which is a component activity... 
import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    editstate: Ember.inject.service('edit-state'),
    actions: {
        createCat() {
            WORKS this.get('editstate').saveCatChanges();
            FAILS Ember.get(this.get('editstate'), 'saveCatChanges')

        }
    }            
});
```

The "FAILS" version has no definition for "this" when it gets to the service.  Really?  So there's no "saveCatChanges" defined and it exceptions out.  But the same code in the service, called with the WORKS variant, has a "this" and all is well.

Why?  Huh?  And the only reason I tracked this down was sheer frustration in trying to document it, so, huh, what?

Please help me understand.  Ember is confusing me with when I need foo.bar vs Ember.get(this, 'foo').bar vs Ember.get(this,Ember.get(this, 'foo'),'bar), but this was especially unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

```
WORKS this.get('editstate').saveCatChanges();
```

This works, because you are getting the `editstate` object and calling the function `saveCatChanges` function.

```
FAILS Ember.get(this.get('editstate'), 'saveCatChanges')
```

It didn't fails.It's doing job of retrieving the property. but you didn't invoke it.

`Ember.get(this.get('editstate'), 'saveCatChanges')()` is equivalent to `this.get('editstate').saveCatChanges()`

Here is what is your motto?. `Ember.get` is used to retrieve the property from the object which you are sending in the first parameter. in your case, you are trying to get function, which is not ideal. you don't need to use `Ember.get` to do this.

`Ember.get` is using `this.get` in backend. both are same. `Ember.Object` has get/set method, normal plain object will not have get/set method, in that case we can use `Ember.get`/`Ember.set`

1. `foo.bar` -> Dont use it. always use get/set method.
2. `Ember.get(this, 'foo').bar` -> if `foo` is Ember object, then `this.get('foo').get('bar')` or `Ember.ger(this,'foo.bar')`.
3. `Ember.get(this,Ember.get(this, 'foo'),'bar)` -> this is wrong, second argument should be the property name but you are providing the object. and it won't accept thrid parameter.(Ember.set is accepting three parameter)

Refer this answer-[difference-between-ember-get-and-this-get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40606827/difference-between-ember-get-and-this-get/40607455#40607455)

Refer:
https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/namespaces/Ember/methods/get?anchor=get