# Accessing Store data in service Ember js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to peek a store from the service, by injecting the store in my service. The `peekRecord` function returns a Class. What is the best way to access the record that the store returns?

As peekRecord is synchronous I tried like:

```
const hasPermission = this.get('store').peekRecord('system/permission','PlatformRead');
console.log(hasPermission.data);
```

Is there any Ember specific way to access the record that's returned from the store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Ember.Object`'s `get()` to retrieve value and `set()` method to update the value.

```
hasPermission.get('someProperty');
hasPermission.set('someProperty', 'New value of someProperty');
```

where `someProperty` could defined upon the model:

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';

export default Model.extend({
    someProperty: attr('string');
});
```

Using these methods will also make sure computed properties are recomputed (by default, if depending values have changed in the meantime). I highly recommend reading through this section of the Ember guides: [The Object model](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.15.0/object-model/).

Btw, personally, as I switched to ESLint from JSHint and applied [eslint-plugin-ember](https://github.com/ember-cli/eslint-plugin-ember), I use `get()` and `set()` methods from Ember [namespace](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/namespaces/Ember).
In such a case, instead of writing `hasPermission.get('data')` you would write `Ember.get(hasPermission, 'data');`. Bringing it even further when it comes to code readability, you could do sth like this:

```
// your-app/services/your-service.js
// ... imports

const {
   get,
   inject,
   Service,
} = Ember;

export default Service.extend({
   store: inject.service(),

   someFunction(){
       const hasPermission = this.get('store').peekRecord('system/permission','PlatformRead');
       console.log(get(hasPermission, 'someProperty'));
   },
});
```

The following Stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40606827/difference-between-ember-get-and-this-get/40607455#40607455) touches slightly the difference between `this.get()` and `Ember.get()`.