# How to get the data object from a single record in the model?

Tags: ember.js, model

Recently this became a bug in my application, although I don't know what changed to make it so (I haven't upgraded the version of Ember, which is still 1.13). What I need to find out is how to access the object of a single record on the model in the conventional way.

I have the following code to filter my `model` based on two other properties:

```
  recordsBySelectedShapeAndColor = get(this, "model").filter(function(rec) {
    //filter the model by the chosen shape and color
    return (
      get(rec, "shape") === theShape &&
      get(rec, "color") === theColor
    );
  });
```

I then need to create a summary of those filtered records, which I'm using `reduce()` for, but if that filter returns only one record, then `reduce` doesn't return the right results, so I have the following condition:

```
if (recordsBySelectedShapeAndColor.length < 2) {
  summary = recordsBySelectedShapeAndColor[0]._data;
} else {
  summary = recordsBySelectedShapeAndColor.reduce(function(a, b) {
...
}
```

It's the line within the `if` that is no longer returning the a simple object, so I changed it to `summary = recordsBySelectedShapeAndColor[0]._internalModel._data;` and it works, but it seems fishy (`._data` always did too). Is it code smell to be accessing underscored properties? If so, how can I get just the data from that single record on the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get(recordsBySelectedShapeAndColor, 'firstObject')`

Comment: Geez, is that all?? I had tried `recordsBySelectedShapeAndColor.firstObject` and didn't get anywhere because it returned a class that I couldn't see the data object in, so I figured I still wasn't there yet. Thank you!!!
This also works, not sure which is better to use: `recordsBySelectedShapeAndColor.get("firstObject")`

Comment: In ember just always use `.get`! And this is not a real `Array`, but an Ember `Enumerable`.

Comment: Thanks @Lux. From this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40606827/difference-between-ember-get-and-this-get), there seems to be a good use case for `Ember.get()` over `this.get()` if you don't know whether your object is an Ember object, because `get()` will continue to work while `this.get()` will fail if it's not an Ember object.