# Ember referencing property or getter

Tags: ember.js

I'm a bit confused as to when to reference a property and when to use a getter, and why.

For example, a controller might inject a service for an uptodate `location` property:

```
export default Controller.extend({
    maps        : service(),

    location    : computed('maps.location', function() {
        return this.get('maps').getLocation()
    }),
```

But `getLocation` in the service is a simple getter:

```
getLocation() {
    return this.get('location')
},
```

Why not use one of these:

```
this.get('maps').location
this.get('maps').get('location')
this.get('maps.location')
```

and prevent having to write getters for every parameter? In the spirit of convention over configuration, isn't writing getters a bit redundant?

Simply put, when looking at examples and tutorials, I see different patterns:

- `service.property`
- `service.get('property')`
- `service.getProperty()`

What is correct, when and why?

---

Tutorials and forum posts online vary broadly in Ember version targeted. Often even the 2.x branch. I'm using 3.8 at the moment.

Comment: what ember version are you using (if >= 3.1, this affects the answer I'd give)

Comment: I'm using 3.8 at the moment. I've edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like @NullVoxPopuli mentioned, it depends on your ember version, but I'm going to assume you're using `> 3` or latest.

My first note is that I've almost exclusively moved to importing and using [the `get` function](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.5/functions/@ember%2Fobject/get), which, as [defined by the documentation](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.5/functions/@ember%2Fobject/get) and described very well by [@Pavol in another similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40606827/difference-between-ember-get-and-this-get/40607455), allows you to be ignorant of whether or not you are trying to get a property on a plain javascript object or an `Ember.Object`.

To answer more directly, I'm not sure what the service you're referring to is trying to accomplish, but based on what you've posted, you could very well just call `get(this, 'maps.location')` within your controller, and remove or ignore that service method.

The Ember documentation also points out that as long as you know the method you want to use from an injected service, you can just call it off the current Ember.Object without using `get`; like this:

```
export default Controller.extend({
    maps: service(),

    location: computed('maps.location', function() {
        return this.maps.getLocation()
    })...
```

The reason you may want to use `get` is if you're not sure a property your accessing is computed or not.

> When you call `get` on a computed property, the function will be called and the return value will be returned instead of the function itself.

Comment: Personally, I prefer using as much native JS as possible. so my preference would be `this.maps.location`

Comment: Am I correct to assume that a getter in a service that simply returns a single property from the service is _never_ necessary? Seeing it in tutorials is either for an older version, or simply cargo cult code?

Comment: correct. it's never needed, you can just directly access stuff. the method in your example `getLocation`, (to be blunt) is literally pointless

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli That's not true for all cases. `this.get()` is still required for some edge cases. They are listed in release notes for Ember 3.1: https://www.emberjs.com/blog/2018/04/13/ember-3-1-released.html#toc_es5-getters-for-computed-properties-2-of-4

Comment: how many people are using those edge cases though? 
fwiw, I think explicit use of not chaining properties in strings together is a huge benfit. but also, js has the elvis operator in the TC39 process somewhere. so... that'd be excited if/when that lands